# com.square.okhttp.OkhttpClient setRetryOnConnectionFailure isRetried

Tags: okhttp, square

So just curious, is there any way to know whether the connection is already retried, or in a retry state?

i already try some ut like this one https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4963#issuecomment-484847682

or using wiremock like this one
https://wiremock.org/docs/simulating-faults/